# Convergence of the sequence defined by $f_n=n1_{(1/n ,1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

Does {$f_n$} defined by $f_n= n 1_{(1/n , 1]}$ converge to $0$ pointwise?. Clearly $\int f_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't since $f_n(1)=n$.

Comment: If I make it $(1/n , 1)$, then does the sequence converge to $0$?. Or the same sequence defined for all $n$ except for $n=1$?

Comment: No. Take $3/4$. I think you mean $(0,1/n)$ then it converges pointwiste to $0$. If you take $n^21_{(0,1/n)}$ you also have $\int f_n \rightarrow \infty$.